# JavaFX - Combobox Expands Downward Off Screen (Post 8u60)

Tags: javafx

I thought this bug was supposed to be fixed a long time ago... but when I place a ComboBox near the bottom of a window it expands downward and off the screen. I think the reason it does this is because there are other controls above it, so rather than "bump" into those it just expands downward instead. Why doesn't the combo box expand *over* the the rest of the layout? <strike>All I know is that when I add some padding above it, it will expand upward instead of downward.</strike>

Example:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        ObservableList<String> choiceList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        choiceList.addAll("Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3", "Choice4");
        ComboBox<String> choices = new ComboBox<>(choiceList);
        choices.setMinWidth(100);

        Button button1 = new Button("First Button");
        button1.setMinWidth(150);
        Button button2 = new Button("Second Button");
        button2.setMinWidth(150);

        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        layout.getChildren().addAll(button1, button2, choices);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Example");
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[Image of window displayed by the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znpqe.png)

Anybody got a fix for this?

Comment: This is strange, as the list should popup _above_ the stage. Can you post a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, if in your case, you are moving your main application window to the bottom of the screen and the combo box is still dropping down and being cut off so that some contents of the popup are not visible, then it may well be a bug.  But my guess is, that if that is what is happing, that it is a system specific issue as I cannot replicate such an issue on OS X.  If that is the case, try a Java 9 early access release and see if the issue still replicates, and if it does you could file a [bug report](http://bugreport.java.com).

---

This is not bug, it is by design.

The ComboBox popup is internally implemented as a [PopupControl](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/PopupControl.html).  A PopupControl is a new window, which isn't constrained to lie within the bounds of its parent window (your main stage).   JavaFX has logic to ensure that popups such as the ContextMenus and ComboBox popups are shown within the visible screen area, not the owning stage area.

If you move your main application towards the top of the screen, then open the combo box popup, the popup will drop down because there is room on the screen to display it.  But if you move the main application towards the bottom of the screen, then the open the combo box popup, the popup will drop up (I don't know a better way to explain that concept ;-) because there is no room to display the popup if it were to drop down.

Drop up sample.  Created by running your example code on OS X, moving the main application window near the bottom of the screen and opening the combo box popup.

[image]